# How to determine which server is more suitable for downloading distributed files on CDN servers using PHP?

Tags: php, time, download, cdn

Imagine that I uploaded a file on multiple servers (CDN) and now, I would like to choose the best one regarding to its download time and proximity when I want to download one of them. How can I do it if I want to implement it with PHP? How can I make the best choice?

Comment: The CDN is usually supposed to do that for you. That's its point

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you're creating your own CDN, which I'd highly recommend not to do. Existing CDNs are highly fine-tuned and have more servers you can possible get, for a more than reasonable price.

If you want to know how they work, there's a lot of content on the internet on the subject:

- [How are the optimal end-points chosen from a CDN when content is served?](http://blog.ashwinraghav.com/2012/02/20/how-are-the-optimal-end-points-chosen-from-a-cdn-when-content-is-served/)
- [Amazons Cloudfront page](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) (scroll down, there's a **lot** of information!)
- [How does CDN DNS work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103753/how-does-cdn-dns-work)
- [How does a CDN work on the tech side?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25374/how-does-a-cdn-work-on-the-tech-side)

Comment: Yes, I need to do that as a university project. So I need to know what I have to do.